# Visual Studio Common User Library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

How can I create a library for myself that I can easily use across all visual studio projects? Basically I would like to have something similar to using system that always appears and both debug and release versions are properly used.

Essentially I do not want to have to do anything to be able to use these libraries. I just want to start a project and use them... just like one does with the built in libraries(at most maybe add using statement).

In fact, I would also like for the library project to be added to the current solution so I can modify it on the fly without having to open up a new instance.

The library will just contain utility helper functions to make my life easier and I don't want to have to spend time screwing around installing them on each project I create just to use them and don't want to spend a lot of time when I want to update the library.

It shouldn't be too hard. Maybe create the library solution, use custom build events... and some type of custom vs script to add the solution, reference, and using statement to the current project?

Comment: @HansPassant I'd like to be able to include them in existing solutions too without any real work(hotkey or menu item). Is there a master template that I can edit for C# WPF projects?